# Is it possible to open a modal on input focus and enter a value to the input from the modal?

Tags: jquery, input, focus, modal-dialog

novice jquery user here. I'm looking to open a modal when an input is focused/selected and input a value to the input from a button in the modal.

So the events would be.
1. Focus an input.
2. Open a modal.
3. Input a value into the input through the use of a button.
4. Close the modal when button is closed.

Many thanks.

Comment: That's great, and sounds totally doable. However, SO isn't a "write my code for me" service, so: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 2):

You'll want either `prompt()`:

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input[name=myNameHere]', function(){
    var input = prompt('The Question', 'Suggested answer');
    $(this).val(input);
});
```

Or a more advanced dialog via [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true, autoOpen:false});

        $("#result").focus(function () {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
        });

        $('#accept').click(function (){
            $('#result').val($('#source').val());
            $('#dialog').dialog("close");
        });

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

 <input type="text" id="result"> 
 </div>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    Enter value <input type="text" id="source" /><br/>
    <input type="button" id="accept" value="OK" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```